# Tokens in a Reports Title and Format section?

Tags: civireport, tokens, reports, custom-reports

Is it possible to use tokens in Report Title/Header/Footer? Gave it a quick try with `{contact.first_name}` and failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the tokens are not supported in report headers or footers. They will be rendered as plain text or html.

You could use alterMailParams hook to process and replace the tokens.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

maybe in the future, using SearchKit for reports will offer this support